# Obtaining field value after applying onkeypress

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a JavaScript function that ensures user only types numbers.

I call it by using `onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event, 'MaxRate', 1300, 62500);"`.

```
function onlyNumbers(evt, id, value, maxRange)
{
    var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

    var answer = false;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    // if user provided id
    if(id)
    {
        // we obtain the new value
        var newValue = ( (document.getElementById(id).value) + String.fromCharCode(charCode) );
        // we check for range limits
        if(maxRange && newValue > maxRange)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // we check to see if value has changed, therefore we will highlight text
        if(value)
        {
            highlight_text_on_change(id, value, newValue);
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function highlight_text_on_change(id, value, newValue)
{
    if(newValue)
    {
        if(newValue == value)
        {
            document.getElementById(id+'_name').style.color = '';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(id+'_name').style.color = 'red';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(document.getElementById(id).value == value)
        {
            alert("UnHighlighting text");
            document.getElementById(id+'_name').style.color = '';
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Highlighting text");
            document.getElementById(id+'_name').style.color = 'red';
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The function first of all validates to check and see if the user has pressed a number key, and then if the value for the number key has changed then the text that has `id+'name'` will have the text color change to red indicating that it changed. The only problem I have is that, let's say default value of the textfield is 1300, if the user types 6, the value changes to 13006, or 13060, or 13600, or 16300, or 61300 and the field highlights, but if the user presses backspace afterwards, then the field does not un-highlight because the backspace action won't register properly. Is there any way at all I can know where exactly user pressed backspace, or obtain the newly formed value for the textfield without applying it to the texfield until I check that new value to be valid?

Answer (score 2):

It's not good to use keypress event to detect value of a field after you press a key. Use keyup instead.

Keypress event will be fired after you press the key but **before** the data is registered into the field.

Keyup event will be fired after you press the key but **after** the data is registered into the field and also count backspace

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/yymEH/

Comment: That made it even weirder. keyup causes even letters to be accepted now. But thank you for the jsfiddle, I shall practise there

Comment: Number filter has to be made in onkeydown then do a return false if NaN